# How to detect if the Android phone fully support the call recording function?

Tags: android, audio-recording, phone-call

I've implemented the call recorder function with VOICE_CALL feature:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_CALL

It can record the voice from both of incoming call and outgoing call very clearly .

But it only works perfectly on some handsets, such as Asus padfone, or hTC ONE (m7).

Some brands, such as hTC m8, Sony Z1, or Samsung S3 , they only record my voice while somebody's making a call to me. But they can't record the incoming call's voice.

My questions:

1. Is there any programmatically way to detect if this handset can record incoming call's voice correctly?
2. Why the same brand phone have different result? for example, some hTC m8 can record perfectly, but some hTC m8 can only record one side.

Thanks in advance for any help:)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, Android suggests developers to use MediaRecorder or AudioRecord to record calls, these are standard APIs, Android itself supports call recording.

Some manufacturers purposely disabled the call recording feature, for example:

- Galaxy Note3 Android 4.3 records calls well.
- Galaxy Note3 Android 4.4 in Finland, China etc records calls well, in other countries it can only record noise.
- LG G2 D800 Android 4.3 can not record the caller's voice.
- LG G2 D800 Android 4.4 works very well.

Why did manufacturers do this? Because required by the mobile operator, limited by the local law etc.

Is there any programmatic way to detect if this handset can record incoming call's voice correctly? Unfortunately, no.

How to fix the recording problem? Using standard API is hard to fix the problem. Usually you need to root the phone, then some recorder apps (for example "Boldbeast Call Recorder", "Call Recorder" etc) can change audio related settings to fix it. [Boldbeast Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boldbeast.recorder) also uses special recording parameters to fix the problem for many phones without root.